# Ant needs tools.jar and unable to find it

Tags: java, ant, tools.jar

I am putting together a dev environment for a Java program and after the first try of my Ant build scripts I got this error:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
```

While the path to the jdk is correct, the tools.jar really wasn't there.  Is it actually supposed to be there or did I get some config/installation thing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have JRE-only Java installed. See http://openjdk.java.net/install/ perhaps.  What OS do you have there?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu.  At first I installed only JRE then I installed JDK.  They could possibly be mis-configured :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's there on my machine.  I'm running Sun JDK 1.6.0_21 on Windows XP SP3.

Are you sure you have the JDK?  Is it possible that you only have the JRE?

Comment: I have both, jdk and jre.  but that particular directory got downloaded and extracted as jdk which makes me assume it is jdk lol.

Comment: To be more specific, add this to .bashrc `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin`

Comment: To be yet more specific, if you're running a build script that invokes an Ant build, you may need to actually set the `export` in your `~/.bashrc`. I found just doing it in the terminal before running one particular `build.sh` didn't solve the problem. I also set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` rather than just `/usr/`; `JAVA_HOME` should be the install directory of the JDK, since Ant will (I think) look in `JAVA_HOME/bin` and `JAVA_HOME/lib`.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer?  It's not even an answer, per se.

Comment: I was just thinking the smae as @HeathHunnicutt, it seems everywhere I go to find answers to this question I'm met with "you must only have JRE installed" I know I have `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/` so wtf

Answer (score 66):

It seems like you can have Java installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk but only have the JRE, not the JDK. This fixed it for me:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`

Comment: You'll also need to redirect JAVA_HOME to point to the jdk and not the jre.

Comment: Also works for java 8: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: Isn't this a bug in Ubuntu then? Shouldn't the `ant` package depend on the JDK?

Answer (score 19):

Note: On CentOS / RHEL installing `java-1.x.0-openjdk` will not be enough. Also install `java-1.x.0-openjdk-devel`.

Comment: thanks, I wonder why a jdk which is a java developer kit requires an extra devel package....

Answer (score 5):

On Debian, after installing Ant with `apt-get install ant`, I've encountered the same error when running it:

`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar`

Indeed, there's no mention of any `tools.jar` anywhere in `/usr/lib`, although `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64` itself does exist.

---

https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=java-6-openjdk-amd64%2Flib%2Ftools.jar

As per the search above, `java-6-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar` appears to be part of `openjdk-6-jdk`, which indeed didn't get installed with ant (since it's only marked as suggested (https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ant)).

**`apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`**

Answer (score 5):

```
apt install defalut-jdk # this doesn't contain some file, like tools.jar...
apt install openjdk-8-jdk # this contains all files.
```

Comment: Even if your answer is really helpful I believe that it can be improved by adding some explanation. Follow the link to know more [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu I've just need to install JDK 
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

..and you can always search for all available versions with

```
$ sudo apt-cache search openjdk | grep ^openjdk
```

From the website https://openjdk.java.net/install/ we can read

> The **openjdk-7-jre** package contains just the Java Runtime Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then install the **openjdk-7-jdk** package.

Comment: Android has not yet been ported to Java 7 :/

Comment: thank you @sobi3ch this solved my problem.  Don't know who down voted you but I upvoted your correct answer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS .

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

> % sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
>
> % sudo update-alternatives --config java

select the option that has the path

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java

Worked for me on an ubuntu 10.4

u can try to put your JAVA_HOME also, as follows:

> % sudo export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/javac | sed "s:/bin/javac::")

Answer (score 2):

Installing the jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin (from the oracle.com site) via unzip does not result in a tools.jar.  I guess that file is created by the "make-jpkg" script. Once I did that, and installed the resulting .deb file, everything was fine.
I really hate oracle's lawyers.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have jdk installed, you'll need to redirect JAVA_HOME to point to it.

Here's one weird trick you can put into your .profile to set JAVA HOME properly, no matter which java you have:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -e /usr/bin/java)))
# Test for jdk installed above jre
if [ -x $JAVA_HOME/../bin/java ]; then export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $JAVA_HOME); fi
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu I've fixed this problem by installing package

```
openjdk-7-jre-lib
```

tools.jar appeared after that.

(I know this is an old post, but comment in hope that it will be helpful for somebody lurking for answer like I was today.)