# Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a project using **ant** but I keep receiving this error on issuing `ant clean`:

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
```

I've tried to change JAVA_HOME to point to JDK and exported PATH variables, but still to no avail. Here's what they look like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Here's what my /etc/environment file looks like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/$
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

Comment: Try with this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559956/ant-needs-tools-jar-and-unable-to-find-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate tools.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730815/unable-to-locate-tools-jar)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by OscarGz in the comment, you should be able to find your answer in
[Ant needs tools.jar and unable to find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559956/ant-needs-tools-jar-and-unable-to-find-it).

**Short summary:** Install the JDK (Java Development Kit) with the matching version.  In Debian-based systems, the package may be called `openjdk-7-jdk` (or later versions).  You might also need to set the Java version which is actually used by invoking the `update-alternatives` tool for java and javac:

```
update-alternatives --config javac
update-alternatives --config java
```

Manually setting environment variables should then not be necessary.